# State in ApiController

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api

I need to provide an api to a long running windows service which does a bunch of processing and retains a memory of that history. An api is required to provide status on current activity levels of the system (records processed, records waiting to be processed, etc).

I was wanting to use a self-hosted Owin ApiController to provide a nice interface to the system. However, the ApiController is completely stateless and there is no method (after searching dozens of IoC posts) for injecting an already active instance into the controller.

Is there a way to provide a class instance to an ApiController?

Comment: Can you not store state in a database or a file?

Comment: remember web api should be `REST`, so you should really figure out how to have some sort of tracing/session for `REST`

Comment: I've used WCF api's previously and it worked great to control a collection of worker threads. We have a collection of worker objects each retain state and have start/stop methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can inject an old instance of the controller, because you get a new instance every time you perform a request.

However you can create a singleton object with a collection inside, and you can inject it into the controller constructor and use in every request.

You can also use some sort of persistence such as DB, that you can run on your device.

Here is an example for a singleton class:

```
using System;

public class Singleton
{
   public Dictionary<string,object> State {get; private set;}
   private static Singleton instance;

   private Singleton() {
        State = new Dictionary<string,object>();
   }

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null)
         {
            instance = new Singleton();
         }
         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to inject a long running instance into a fresh ApiController as each call is marshalled?

Comment: a singleton instance can preserved for the lifetime of the application so as long as your server is up you can keep the state.

Comment: How do I create a singleton instance?

Comment: @Gavin I added an example

Comment: So I used your idea a little bit differently, but with the static variable. Basically, within my stateful class that is busy computing (stuff), I created a static variable. I then set the variable and then accessed it from the ApiController. Works a charm.

Comment: Great, just be aware that if share this variable across multiple request you are exposed to concurrency issues.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you can get Session state in web api controller, it is going to be questionable solution, instead, I would recommend going the following way:

- include [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) as dependancy and use it for long running tasks
- Use [signal-r to to push state of background task](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/tracking-progress.html)
- return JobID from your API method and use it on the client to subscribe to signal-r hub